# OneHotEncoding multiple columns in dataset at once

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Consider the following simple snipped dataset:

- 2 Columns: `X`, `Y`.
- Both `X` and `Y` columns have only 3 optional category values

I want to onehotencode these columns.

My try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('./forestfires.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(X[:, 4:12])
X[:, 4:12] = imputer.transform(X[:, 4:12])

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

At the current state, it only encodes the first column. I can't really understand `sklearn` documentation for this function `ColumnTransformer`. How would I select multiple columns to encode all at once?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) it says you can specify the name of the columns you want the transformer to be applied to:

```
cols = X.columns  # list of strings with col names
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), cols)], remainder='passthrough')
```

With you current code you specifically transform only the first column by passing a list with single index: `[0]`.

Comment: So if I want it to encode first and second column, should I code `cols = [0, 1]`?

Comment: When I code `[0, 1, 2, 3]` it won't work (As I want to encode 4 columns). It do work for 3 columns.

Comment: You have to include more details in order for me to grasp why it does not work. Does it throw an error / exception?

Comment: I do this code:  `ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0, 1, 2, 3])], remainder='passthrough')`. This runs fine. When I try to print the first line of `X` (`X[0]`) I get error: `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed`. But I I'd code `[0, 1, 2]` It does print without an error

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
feature_names = [] # Pass your column names to be encoded here
enc_data = enc.fit_transform(dataframe[[feature_names]]).toarray()
enc_columns_data = enc.get_feature_names_out(feature_names)
enc_data = pd.DataFrame(enc_data, columns=enc_columns_data)
```